# Null при чтении файла из ресурсов

Tags: c#

Код чтения файла:

```
    Stream stream;
    string external_js;

    using (stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("vldb.js")) ;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
         external_js = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Выдает ошибку

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentNullException" в
>   mscorlib.dll

в строке

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

Файл лежит в ресурсах и с параметром "Внедренный ресурс", но все равно выдает ошибку при компиляции.

Comment: после первого using надо убрать ;

Answer (score 2):

Вы знаете, что делает оператор `using`?
Он очищает ресурсы после использования (а точнее - вызывает метод `Dispose` у объекта).

Первая конструкция `using` содержит только пустой оператор `;`. И после ее выполнения в переменной `stream` лежит уже очищенный объект.

Предлагаю заменить код на:

```
string external_js;

using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("vldb.js"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
     external_js = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

А это, полагаю, просто неточное высказывание:

> ...но все равно выдает ошибку при компиляции.

Так не может быть, Exception'ы при компиляции не выдаются, они выдаются только в процессе работы программы.

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку
http://clip2net.com/s/3shbnXF